# Is it the correct use of "result in", in the following quotation?

Tags: usage

> Making use of the technological tools does not always result in a good ending.

I want to say using technology is not always good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "result in" is OK.

However, the word *the* before it is not needed, since you mean *any* "technology tools" and not a specific one you were speaking about earlier (unless this is not true).

Also, IMHO *technological* sounds jarring here - I don't hear it often with the word "tools" so it brings to my mind you are talking about some weird, special type of tool and not what is typically meant by "technology" (i.e. computers, software, portable devices).  I would just use "technology*.